# send a text from svelte app to twilio function

Tags: api, cors, twilio, http-post, twilio-api

Still can't figure out this Cors thing its pretty annoying. Trying to test sending a text from an input to twilio. I want to text from my phone to a dynamic number. I keep getting cors error no matter what i do? I am definitely doing something wrong, am i not allowed to send from local host?

SVELTE APP

```
let phoneNumber = "";

const handleSendText = () => {
    fetch("https://svelte-service-9106.twil.io/sms", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        to: phoneNumber,
        from: "+11111111111",
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("failed");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

```
 <input type="text" bind:value={phoneNumber} />
 <button on:click={handleSendText}>Send</button>
```

TWILIO FUNCTION

```
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback){
  const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
  
  const messageDetails = {
    body: "Ahoy, Svelte developer!",
    to: event.to,
    from: event.from,
  }
  
  const response = new Twilio.Response();
  
  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:5000",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };
        
  response.setHeaders(headers);
  
  try {
    const message = await twilioClient.messages.create(messageDetails);
    response.setBody({
      status: `Your message was sent successfully with SID: ${message.sid}`
    });
    return callback(null, response);
  } catch(error) {
    response.setBody({
      status: error
    });
    return callback(response);
  }
}
```

ERROR
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your Function, deployed it to my own Twilio account and was able to make successful `fetch` requests to it from `localhost:5000`.

However, if I caused an error by, for example, using an incorrect `from` number, then I got the CORS error. The issue is that your Function is returning the `response` object as the first argument to the `callback` function. That argument is reserved for error objects, not for responses, and Twilio Functions will create its own response when it receives an error as the first argument to the callback function. That response does not include CORS headers, so you get the CORS error.

The way to deal with this is to send your response and set the status code on it yourself.

So, update your Function to:

```js
  try {
    const message = await twilioClient.messages.create(messageDetails);
    response.setBody({
      status: `Your message was sent successfully with SID: ${message.sid}`
    });
    return callback(null, response);
  } catch(error) {
    response.setBody({
      status: error.message
    });
    response.setStatusCode(400);
    return callback(null, response);
  }
```

You can see that in the `catch` block I am setting the status code to 400 and returning the response object as the second argument to the callback.

Now, your front-end code is also not exposing the error that you would get back from this, mainly because it throws its own exception when the response is not correct. Try updating to parse the body of the error and throw an error using the `status` property that you set in the error.

```js
fetch("https://svelte-service-9106.twil.io/sms", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    to: phoneNumber,
    from: "+111111111111",
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      response.json().then((body) => { 
        throw new Error(body.status);
      })
    } else {
    console.log("Success"); }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Once you update like this you will still get an error, but the error will contain the error message from the API and you will be able to fix that.

Comment: an excellent explanation with working code! I do get an error : "ncaught (in promise) Error: The number  is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify  at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers." Does this mean i can only send to my own phone number? what about other numbers?

Comment: You can only send to your own number (or numbers you verify) while you have a trial account. To be able to send to any number you need to upgrade your account.